# Convert a PlaneProjection into a MatrixTransform

Tags: silverlight

I have a plane projection as follows:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Red" Margin="50">
    <Rectangle.Projection>
        <PlaneProjection RotationX="-40"/>
    </Rectangle.Projection>
</Rectangle>
```

For various reasons I would like to use a MatrixTransform instead. Does anyone know what the equivalent MatrixTransform  would be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `PlaneProjection` is a non-linear transformation while the `MatrixTransform` is:

http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/01/Non-Affine-Transforms-in-Silverlight.html

There will be no way to express the exact same prjection with a linear transform.

If you are transforming an image or non-interactive element you may split it in two triangles to get a good "3d" effect without using a projection. For example this cube uses this approach (SL 2.0 code there):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/CubeProject.aspx

Finally if you just need the transformation matrix, you can access it from the `ProjectionMatrix` property.

```
var matrix = (myElement.Projection as PlaneProjection).ProjectionMatrix;
var matrixProjection = new Matrix3DProjection { ProjectionMatrix = matrix };
```

This is also how you can use it to create a `Matrix3DProjection`